# Laplace Transform: Piecewise Function Integrability and Existence of Laplace Transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform, riemann-integration, continuity

I am trying to decide whether the function

$$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
 1, & \text{$t$ is even} \\
 0, & \text{$t$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

has a Laplace transform, or is even integrable in the first place.

I know that (1) a function is Riemann integrable only if it has a finite number of discontinuities (even if those discontinuities themselves are infinite). I also know that (2) a function has a Laplace transform only if it has a finite number of finite discontinuities.

It seems to me that $f(t)$ satisfies (1) and is therefore Riemann integrable. But then I think about how the graph of such a function would look like, and it doesn't make sense to me how it would be Riemann integrable?

As for (2), although the discontinuities are finite, there is an infinite number of them as we integrate from $0$ to $\infty$, which is what is required for the Fourier transform. Therefore, I'd say that it does **not** satisfy (2)?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this and explain.

EDIT: What's with all of the down-votes? This is a textbook problem from the end-of-chapter-1 textbook problems of *An Introduction to Laplace Transform and Fourier Series* by Dyke:

> For each of the following functions, determine which has a Laplace transform. If it exists, find it; if it does not, say briefly why.
>
> (f) $$f(t) =
> \begin{cases}
>  1, & \text{$t$ is even} \\
>  0, & \text{$t$ is odd}
> \end{cases}$$

I asked this question precisely because I thought it didn't make sense. Not sure why I'm getting down-voted here.

EDIT2: So given the definition of Riemann integrability, what exactly is it about this function that makes it not Riemann integrable? What condition does it fail? $f(t)$ *does* technically have a finite number of discontinuities, so that condition is satisfied.

Comment: Where is this function defined?

Comment: What happens when t is neither, like $1.5$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f(t) =
\begin{cases}
 1, & \text{$t$ is even} \\
 0, & \text{$t$ is odd}
\end{cases}$ means the integers, right?

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Yes, that's what I'm confused about. How could it be Riemann integrable, then? I suspect it is not. But the function *does* have a finite number of discontinuities, right? And so it technically satisfies the definition of Riemann integrability?

Comment: What is the measure on the integers? What does integrability mean? Riemann integrability has no meaning here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is an end-of-chapter textbook problem from a Laplace transform textbook that I am self-studying. Are you saying that the problem doesn't make sense?

Comment: Unless the text book uses highly non-standard definitions the question does not make sense.

Comment: Ok, see my edit.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/olz4oyelq2 $$$$ Could you imagine trying to integrate this? It's a collections of dots. Essentially, you have a function that sporadically has height of 0 or 1, and infinitesimal width. The only function where integrating like this is allowed is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Yes, my thoughts exactly. So given the definition of Riemann integrability, what exactly is it about this function that makes it not Riemann integrable? What condition does it fail? $f(t)$ *does* technically have a finite number of discontinuities, so that condition is satisfied.

Comment: @ThePointer It didn't really have any continuity to begin with... The only integrals you can do here are $\int_n^n$ where $n$ goes through the integers. The integral evaluates to $0$ anyway. Finally, the Laplace of $0$ is $0$. That's punching through multiple technicalities and theorems to get there, but that's an answer.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Yes, I didn't want to use the "area under the curve" analogy, but these integrals would obviously have no "area" anyway. But technically they are (piecewise) continuous, no?

Comment: Actually, Wikipedia defines the concept of "continuity' only within the context of the real numbers, so I guess it doesn't make sense to discuss it outside of this context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two reasonable explanations.

1. Since the Laplace transfrom is only defined for suitable functions $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$, and your function is $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$, it does not have a Laplace transform.
2. The author made a mistake, and instead meant to define $f(x)=1$ for even integers and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. In this case, $f$ has infinitely many discontinuities, so (according to the author) it does not have a Laplace transform.